# Number of cycles that arithmetic instruction takes for 25% improvement in performance?

Tags: computer-architecture

The program has the following proportion of instructions:
Arithmetic: 70%
Load/Store: 10%
Branch: 20%

The question is to `find the number of cycles on average that an arithmetic instruction take for a 25% improvement in performance if load/store and branch instructions are not improved at all?`

How to proceed with such type of questions?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  We want to help you understand concepts, not do exercise-style problems for you (as that would likely help neither you nor anyone else).  Think of this as testing your understanding of the material.  What is preventing you from knowing how to approach this?  What concepts are you fuzzy on?  What have you tried?

Comment: Read what you posted carefully and compare with the homework question you were given. Either you lost something when you posted this question or your homework question is nonsense. As stated it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have 100 fruit: 70 Apples, 10 Lychees and 20 Bananas. You want to reduce the number of apples until you have only 75 fruit left. How many apples do you have to eat?